# if i comment out the . home url, admin works fine, but when included, it gives an error no module named signup, what could be the issue?

Tags: django-admin

```
ImportError at /

No module named 'SignUp'

Exception Location:     C:\Python 3.5\lib\importlib           \__init__.py in import_module, line 126
Python Executable:  C:\Python 3.5\python.exe
Python Version:     3.5.0
Python Path:    

['F:\\geeky\\geobins',
 'C:\\Python 3.5\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.8.12-   py3.5.egg',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\JetBrains\\PyCharm   5.0.4\\helpers\\pycharm',
 'F:\\geeky\\geobins',
  'C:\\Python 3.5\\python35.zip',
 'C:\\Python 3.5\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python 3.5\\lib',
 'C:\\Python 3.5',
 'C:\\Users\\Bryane\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python35\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Python 3.5\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:    Wed, 21 Sep 2016 12:07:44 +0300
```

Here are my urls

```
urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
     #url(r'^$', 'SignUp.views.base', name='base'),
    url(r'^$', 'SignUp.views.home', name='home'),
```

If i comment out the. home url, my admin site works great, but when included, it gives me the import error at /, no module named SighUp, what could be the issue?